# Permissions error on mounted symbolic link

Tags: mount, apache2, symbolic-link

Ive created a symbolic link to a mounted NFS drive to Apache's "images" folder:

```
ls -ltr /var/www/html/images  
/var/www/html/images -> /mnt/mount_name/images
```

Edit:
Ive added the `namei` command output as @Thomas suggested:

```
namei -olm /mnt/mount_name/images/  
f: /mnt/mount_name/images/  
dr-xr-xr-x root       root       /  
drwxr-xr-x user user mnt  
drwxrwxrwx user user mount_name  
drwxrwxrwx user user images
```

When i trying to access an image on that path i am receiving the error below:

> Permission denied because search permissions are missing on a component of the path.

I tried to look for solutions to the problem but encountered several different solutions, Please advice.

Regards,
Yarone

Comment: It seems you are trying to access the path with a normal user and one or more directories have access rights set that prevent you from listing the directory. You can get an overview of the permissions with `sudo namei -olm /mnt/mount_name/images`. You also may want to add the output of that command to your question.

Comment: Ive added the "namei" command output as @Thomas suggested:

Comment: Thank you @RoVo, setting the permissions to 755 did not solve the problem but that post also mentioned that selinux might cause the problem, Ive disabled it and it worked, any idea how to solve it without disabling selinux ?

Comment: The problem was solved by setting "setsebool httpd_use_nfs 1" in selinux, thank you all.